# Translate Function Success into Function then

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to get django-rest-framework running with angularjs. In order to do the authorization I found [django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html) and [angular-django-registration-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth/blob/master/app/scripts/services/djangoAuth.js)

Unfortunately the djangoAuth.js is using the depreciated function success within the 'request' variable and I get the following error message:

> TypeError: $http(...).success is not a function

I tried to rewrite the code using the then function, but only end up in the error-Callback. What do I have to change? Thanks for your help.

djangoAuth.js - Orginal

```
auth
  .service('djangoAuth', function djangoAuth($q, $http, $cookies, $rootScope) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    var service = {
        /* START CUSTOMIZATION HERE */
        // Change this to point to your Django REST Auth API
        // e.g. /api/rest-auth  (DO NOT INCLUDE ENDING SLASH)
        'API_URL': 'localhost:8000/rest-auth',
        // Set use_session to true to use Django sessions to store security token.
        // Set use_session to false to store the security token locally and transmit it as a custom header.
        'use_session': true,
        /* END OF CUSTOMIZATION */
        'authenticated': null,
        'authPromise': null,
        'request': function(args) {
            // Let's retrieve the token from the cookie, if available
            if($cookies.token){
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
            }
            // Continue
            params = args.params || {}
            args = args || {};
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                url = this.API_URL + args.url,
                method = args.method || "GET",
                params = params,
                data = args.data || {};
            // Fire the request, as configured.
            $http({
                url: url,
                withCredentials: this.use_session,
                method: method.toUpperCase(),
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']},
                params: params,
                data: data
            })
            .success(angular.bind(this,function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data, status);
            }))
            .error(angular.bind(this,function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error syncing with: " + url);
                // Set request status
                if(data){
                    data.status = status;
                }
                if(status == 0){
                    if(data == ""){
                        data = {};
                        data['status'] = 0;
                        data['non_field_errors'] = ["Could not connect. Please try again."];
                    }
                    // or if the data is null, then there was a timeout.
                    if(data == null){
                        // Inject a non field error alerting the user
                        // that there's been a timeout error.
                        data = {};
                        data['status'] = 0;
                        data['non_field_errors'] = ["Server timed out. Please try again."];
                    }
                }
                deferred.reject(data, status, headers, config);
            }));
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        'register': function(username,password1,password2,email,more){
            var data = {
                'username':username,
                'password1':password1,
                'password2':password2,
                'email':email
            }
            data = angular.extend(data,more);
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/registration/",
                'data' :data
            });
        },
        'login': function(username,password){
            var djangoAuth = this;
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/login/",
                'data':{
                    'username':username,
                    'password':password
                }
            }).then(function(data){
                if(!djangoAuth.use_session){
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + data.key;
                    $cookies.token = data.key;
                }
                djangoAuth.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("djangoAuth.logged_in", data);
            });
        },
        'logout': function(){
            var djangoAuth = this;
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/logout/"
            }).then(function(data){
                delete $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
                delete $cookies.token;
                djangoAuth.authenticated = false;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("djangoAuth.logged_out");
            });
        },
        'changePassword': function(password1,password2){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/password/change/",
                'data':{
                    'new_password1':password1,
                    'new_password2':password2
                }
            });
        },
        'resetPassword': function(email){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/password/reset/",
                'data':{
                    'email':email
                }
            });
        },
        'profile': function(){
            return this.request({
                'method': "GET",
                'url': "/user/"
            }); 
        },
        'updateProfile': function(data){
            return this.request({
                'method': "PATCH",
                'url': "/user/",
                'data':data
            }); 
        },
        'verify': function(key){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/registration/verify-email/",
                'data': {'key': key} 
            });            
        },
        'confirmReset': function(uid,token,password1,password2){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/password/reset/confirm/",
                'data':{
                    'uid': uid,
                    'token': token,
                    'new_password1':password1,
                    'new_password2':password2
                }
            });
        },
        'authenticationStatus': function(restrict, force){
            // Set restrict to true to reject the promise if not logged in
            // Set to false or omit to resolve when status is known
            // Set force to true to ignore stored value and query API
            restrict = restrict || false;
            force = force || false;
            if(this.authPromise == null || force){
                this.authPromise = this.request({
                    'method': "GET",
                    'url': "/user/"
                })
            }
            var da = this;
            var getAuthStatus = $q.defer();
            if(this.authenticated != null && !force){
                // We have a stored value which means we can pass it back right away.
                if(this.authenticated == false && restrict){
                    getAuthStatus.reject("User is not logged in.");
                }else{
                    getAuthStatus.resolve();
                }
            }else{
                // There isn't a stored value, or we're forcing a request back to
                // the API to get the authentication status.
                this.authPromise.then(function(){
                    da.authenticated = true;
                    getAuthStatus.resolve();
                },function(){
                    da.authenticated = false;
                    if(restrict){
                        getAuthStatus.reject("User is not logged in.");
                    }else{
                        getAuthStatus.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
            return getAuthStatus.promise;
        },
        'initialize': function(url, sessions){
            this.API_URL = url;
            this.use_session = sessions;
            return this.authenticationStatus();
        }

    }
    return service;
  });
```

djangoAuth.js - My Trial

```
auth
.service('djangoAuth', function djangoAuth($q, $http, $cookies, $rootScope) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    var service = {
        /* START CUSTOMIZATION HERE */
        // Change this to point to your Django REST Auth API
        // e.g. /api/rest-auth  (DO NOT INCLUDE ENDING SLASH)
        'API_URL': 'localhost:8000/rest-auth',
        // Set use_session to true to use Django sessions to store security token.
        // Set use_session to false to store the security token locally and transmit it as a custom header.
        'use_session': true,
        /* END OF CUSTOMIZATION */
        'authenticated': null,
        'authPromise': null,
        'request': function(args) {
            // Let's retrieve the token from the cookie, if available
            if($cookies.token){
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
            }
            // Continue
            params = args.params || {}
            args = args || {};
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                url = this.API_URL + args.url,
                method = args.method || "GET",
                params = params,
                data = args.data || {};
            // Fire the request, as configured.
            $http({
                url: url,
                withCredentials: this.use_session,
                method: method.toUpperCase(),
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']},
                params: params,
                data: data
            }).then(
                //Success Callback  
                angular.bind(this,function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data, status);
                }),
                //Error Callback
                angular.bind(this,function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("error syncing with: " + url);
                    // Set request status
                    if(data){
                        data.status = status;
                    }
                    if(status == 0){
                        if(data == ""){
                            data = {};
                            data['status'] = 0;
                            data['non_field_errors'] = ["Could not connect. Please try again."];
                        }
                        // or if the data is null, then there was a timeout.
                        if(data == null){
                            // Inject a non field error alerting the user
                            // that there's been a timeout error.
                            data = {};
                            data['status'] = 0;
                            data['non_field_errors'] = ["Server timed out. Please try again."];
                        }
                    }
                    deferred.reject(data, status, headers, config);                
                })
            );

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        'register': function(username,password1,password2,email,more){
            var data = {
                'username':username,
                'password1':password1,
                'password2':password2,
                'email':email
            }
            data = angular.extend(data,more);
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/registration/",
                'data' :data
            });
        },
        'login': function(username,password){
            var djangoAuth = this;
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/login/",
                'data':{
                    'username':username,
                    'password':password
                }
            }).then(function(data){
                if(!djangoAuth.use_session){
                    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + data.key;
                    $cookies.token = data.key;
                }
                djangoAuth.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("djangoAuth.logged_in", data);
            });
        },
        'logout': function(){
            var djangoAuth = this;
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/logout/"
            }).then(function(data){
                delete $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
                delete $cookies.token;
                djangoAuth.authenticated = false;
                $rootScope.$broadcast("djangoAuth.logged_out");
            });
        },
        'changePassword': function(password1,password2){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/password/change/",
                'data':{
                    'new_password1':password1,
                    'new_password2':password2
                }
            });
        },
        'resetPassword': function(email){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/password/reset/",
                'data':{
                    'email':email
                }
            });
        },
        'profile': function(){
            return this.request({
                'method': "GET",
                'url': "/user/"
            }); 
        },
        'updateProfile': function(data){
            return this.request({
                'method': "PATCH",
                'url': "/user/",
                'data':data
            }); 
        },
        'verify': function(key){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/registration/verify-email/",
                'data': {'key': key} 
            });            
        },
        'confirmReset': function(uid,token,password1,password2){
            return this.request({
                'method': "POST",
                'url': "/password/reset/confirm/",
                'data':{
                    'uid': uid,
                    'token': token,
                    'new_password1':password1,
                    'new_password2':password2
                }
            });
        },
        'authenticationStatus': function(restrict, force){
            // Set restrict to true to reject the promise if not logged in
            // Set to false or omit to resolve when status is known
            // Set force to true to ignore stored value and query API
            restrict = restrict || false;
            force = force || false;
            if(this.authPromise == null || force){
                this.authPromise = this.request({
                    'method': "GET",
                    'url': "/user/"
                })
            }
            var da = this;
            var getAuthStatus = $q.defer();
            if(this.authenticated != null && !force){
                // We have a stored value which means we can pass it back right away.
                if(this.authenticated == false && restrict){
                    getAuthStatus.reject("User is not logged in.");
                }else{
                    getAuthStatus.resolve();
                }
            }else{
                // There isn't a stored value, or we're forcing a request back to
                // the API to get the authentication status.
                this.authPromise.then(function(){
                    da.authenticated = true;
                    getAuthStatus.resolve();
                },function(){
                    da.authenticated = false;
                    if(restrict){
                        getAuthStatus.reject("User is not logged in.");
                    }else{
                        getAuthStatus.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
            return getAuthStatus.promise;
        },
        'initialize': function(url, sessions){
            this.API_URL = url;
            this.use_session = sessions;
            return this.authenticationStatus();
        }

    }
    return service;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to use deferred when you use $http (It already returns a promise). Then you don't need to use angular.bind().

Also you can't pass two arguments into `deferred.resolve()` method [(Second one is a callback)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve).

All you need is to return result from `$http`:

```
'request': function(args) {
        // Let's retrieve the token from the cookie, if available
        if($cookies.token){
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
        }
        // Continue
        params = args.params || {}
        args = args || {};
        var url = this.API_URL + args.url,
            method = args.method || "GET",
            params = params,
            data = args.data || {};
        // Fire the request, as configured.
        return $http({
            url: url,
            withCredentials: this.use_session,
            method: method.toUpperCase(),
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']},
            params: params,
            data: data
        }).catch(
            //Use catch for error handling
            //Error Callback
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error syncing with: " + url);
                // Set request status
                if(data){
                    data.status = status;
                }
                if(status == 0){
                    if(data == ""){
                        data = {};
                        data['status'] = 0;
                        data['non_field_errors'] = ["Could not connect. Please try again."];
                    }
                    // or if the data is null, then there was a timeout.
                    if(data == null){
                        // Inject a non field error alerting the user
                        // that there's been a timeout error.
                        data = {};
                        data['status'] = 0;
                        data['non_field_errors'] = ["Server timed out. Please try again."];
                    }
                }               
            })
        }
```